# How do I see if a value matches another value in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, words

Here's what I have so far.

```
from itertools import permutations

original = str(input('What word would you like to unscramble?: '))

for bob in permutations(original):
    print(''.join(bob))



inputFile = open(dic.txt, 'r')
compare = inputFile.read()
inputFile.close()
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a word unscrambler by having Python find all possible rearrangements of a string and then only print the rearrangements that are actual words, which can be found out by running each rearrangement through a dictionary file (in this case dic.txt) to see if there is a match. I am running Python 3.3, if that matters. What do I need to add in order to compare the rearrangements with the dictionary file?

Comment: For one, you should *store* the permutations instead of just printing them. For another, note that `sorted('dog') == sorted('god')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the permutations in a list, add the dictionary in another list and select those being in both lists…

For example this way:

```
from itertools import permutations

original = str(input('What word would you like to unscramble?: '))

perms = []
for bob in permutations(original):
    perms.append(''.join(bob))



inputFile = open(dic.txt, 'r')
dict_entries = inputFile.read().split('\n')
inputFile.close()

for word in [perm for perm in perms if perm in dict_entries]:
    print word
```

(Assuming the dictionary contains one word per line…)

Comment: This worked! Thanks, but the returned unscrambled values are still in list form. Could you tell me how to make it where it just prints the word?

Comment: I've modified the answer to print words instead of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Read the dictionary file into a list line by line, iterate through each of the rearrangements and check if it's in the dictionary like so:

```
if word in dict_list:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this puts a little more up-front effort into processing the input file, once you've built the `word_dict` it's much more efficient to look up the sorted form of the word rather than build and check for all permutations:

```
def get_word_dict(filename):
    words = {}
    with open(filename) as word_dict:
        for line in word_dict:
           word = line.strip()
           key = sorted(word)
           if key not in words:
               words[key] = []
           words[key].append(word)
    return words

word_dict = get_word_dict('dic.txt')

original = input("What word would you like to unscramble: ")
key = sorted(original)

if key in word_dict:
    for word in word_dict[key]:
        print(word)
else:
    print("Not in the dictionary.")
```

This will be particularly beneficial if you want to look up more than one word - you can process the file once, then repeatedly refer to the `word_dict`.